# How can I align an Include at the bottom?

Tags: android, xml, layout, include

I have a problem since I can't really set an Include layout to stay align bottom and it is disturbing me a lot! Here is my piece of code and I would like you to help me!

Thanks a lot!

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/moncompte"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:background="@drawable/securite"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="193dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:text="@string/myaccount"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="193dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:text="@string/security"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<include layout="@layout/menu_layout" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do this task as like this one:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/White" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/header"
            layout="@layout/header_app" />



        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_footer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

            <include layout="@layout/footer" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

put your layout code in Relative layout and set included layout to     **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>**

Answer (score 0):

in your `menu_layout.xml` add the root Viewgroup's attribute `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Put all the components in a single RelativeLayout parent(as root view) and add the attribute `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/menu_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```